# Import ios certification error, "This certificate was signed by an unknown authority".

Tags: ios, certificate

My team share one apple developer certification, other team members can import it properly, but on my MAC, it will always report error "This certificate was signed by an unknown authority", I am not sure whether it dues to my side KeyChain Access issue, verify/repair doesn't find any defect.

Still not found solution after many try, any suggestion please share? I just wonder how to remove KeyChain Access then install a new one?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue by importing the required certificates into my *login* keychain.