# This certificate was signed by unknown authority keychain

Tags: macos, keychain

Unknowingly i deleted my Keychains System certificates that are generally named as following

```
Software Signing
com.apple.systemdefault
com.apple.kerberos.kdc
Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority
Apple Code Signing Certification Authority
```

now when i try to create developer certificate for iOS development and and install the certificate it gives me an error saying **"This certificate was signed by unknown authority"**

i have no idea how to recover them.

i have been through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12487223/import-ios-certification-error-this-certificate-was-signed-by-an-unknown-autho)

if anyone has work around please help.

Answer (score 6):

if your certificate is not valid, it will have a red "x" and state the reason why. Generally the reason is "This certificate has expired" or "This certificate was signed by an unknown authority. to solve this you need to do the following steps:

1. If your certificate has expired, renew it at the iPhone Portal, download it, and double-click it to add it to your Keychain.
2. If it's "signed by an unknown authority", download the "Apple Worldwide Developer Relations" certificate from the Certificates section of the iPhone Developer portal and double-click it to add it to your Keychain.
3. If your certificate was revoked, delete the certificate from your Keychain, then follow the "Obtaining your iPhone Development Certificate" or "Obtaining your iPhone Distribution Certificate" section in the iPhone Developer Program Portal User Guide to generate a new certificate.
4. Make sure you create a backup of your private key. The steps for doing this are described in the iPhone Developer Program Portal User Guide, under "Saving your Private Key and Transferring to other Systems".
5. If you have the iPhone Developer (or iPhone Distribution) certificate and its associated private key, the Apple WWDR Intermediate certificate is installed, and your certificate is valid, confirm that Online Certificate Status Protocol (OCSP) and Certificate Revocation List (CRL) are set to "Off" in Keychain Access > Preferences > Certificates.
6. if you still have trouble then contact support apple community.

Comment: For step 2 "signed by an unknown authority", Worldwide Developer Relations was not present in the Certificates section of Developer portal. Rather it was here: https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/. Hope it helps others, and this answer helped me solve the issue of codesigning.